# Lightning Data Service - Unable to load event

Tags: lightning-aura-components

It seems like the Lightning Data Service is unable to load Event object. Here is my code:

```
<aura:attribute name="eventObject" type="Object"/>
<force:recordData
  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
  layoutType="FULL"
  targetFields="{!v.eventObject}"
/>
Event Record Subject: {!v.eventObject.Subject}
```

When I convert this for other object types like Contact, it works fine.

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't load, do you get an error ?

Comment: No data is returned as far as I can tell. I'm not seeing an error in the console log either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Event` is not supported by Lightning Data Service.

For details on which objects are supported, you can find the details on its [documentation here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm) under *Supported Objects* section.

Comment: I believe all objects from Activity.. It means Task and Events

Comment: If not specifically called out in documentation, then I would imagine Yes.